# Graph, Planarity, Euler characteristic

Tags: graph-theory

1. Suppose that **G** is  a  connected  simple  planar  graph  on  at  least  three  vertices.   Let **F** denote the number of faces of **G**, and **E** the number of edges.  Prove that ***3F ≤ 2E***.
2. Using (1), prove that if **G** is a connected simple planar graph on ***n ≥ 3*** vertices, then **G** contains at most ***3n−6*** edges.
3. Show that the complete graph on five vertices, $K_5$, is not a planar graph.

Can anyone help me with above questions? Really cant seems to find a way to solve it.

Comment: Think about the "triangles" ($3-$ cycles) that graph might contain. Now double count the edges. ... then use $v-e+f=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every face is made of at least three edges, and every edge is a part of two faces. From that, you need to make an inequality
2. You need to connect the previous inequality with well known $n-m+F=2$ equality, which can be proved by induction
3. This goes from previous point